# Difference between LocalSessionFactoryBean.hibernateProperties.hibernate.c3p0.timeout and HibernateTransactionManager.defaultTimeout

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

In our project's code, we are initialising slave DB Spring HibernateTransactionManager through xml as shown below:

```
<bean id="slaveSessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">com.swiggy.delivery.deliveryboy.model.dao.CustomMySql5Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.slave.showSql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.slave.formatSql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.url">${hibernate.slave.connection.url}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.ReplicationDriver</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.username">${hibernate.slave.connection.username}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.password">${hibernate.slave.connection.password}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">${hibernate.slave.c3p0.min_size}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">${hibernate.slave.c3p0.max_size}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">0</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_idle_time_excess_connections">60</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
</bean>

<bean id="slaveTransactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="slaveSessionFactory" />
        <property name="defaultTimeout" value="10" />
</bean>
```

Here, I want to understand that for DB read timeouts, which value would be used during the transaction, the `hibernate.c3p0.timeout`value of 300 ms or the `defaultTimeout` value of 10 ms.

I tried to go through both Spring and Hibernate docs for this but could not get a clear answer on whether the defaultTImeout would override the hibernate.c3p0.timeout or not.

My hunch is that the timeout value picked would be 300 ms. But cannot confirm that.